# Can't create file with creat system call in c name taken from argument

Tags: c, file, arguments, system

I am trying to create a file, the file name is will be taken from argument. Also the string that will be written is taken from argument! But the creat function returns -1. I could not find why? Any help appreciated!

C Code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fdc;
    int fdo;
    char *wr;
    char *rd;

    if (argc >= 3)
        wr = argv[2];
    else
        wr = "\0";
    printf("wr = %s\n", wr);
    if (argc >= 3)
    {
        fdc = creat(argv[1], O_RDWR);
        printf("fdc = %d\n", fdc);
        if (fdc != -1)
        {
            fdo = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
            printf("fdo = %d", fdo);
            if (fdo != -1)
            {
                printf("a file created\n");
                write (fdo, wr, strlen(wr));
                printf("writed in file that created\n");
                read (fdo, rd, strlen(wr));
                printf("read done\n");
                printf("rd = %s\n",rd);
            }
            close(fdo);
        }
    }
}
```

Command:

```
get_next_line % ./a.out test.txt 012345
```

Output:

```
wr = 012345
fdc = -1
```

Comment: In case of an error you could call `perror` to print a corresponding error message.

Comment: General note: You should always include a complete and minimum program including the headers you are using.

Comment: There is no reason to call both `creat` and `open`.

Comment: Note that `rd` is not pointing to anything valid.

Comment: @stark I suppose it could be useful if you want to maintain separate seek positions.

Comment: @stark `creat()` opens the file in write-only mode.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  If you want to create a file and open RDWR, then open RDWR with mode O_CREAT.  Still has shown no reason to do 2 calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument for creat function should be a mode, not a file flag.

> S_IRWXU
> 00700 user (file owner) has read, write and execute permission
> S_IRUSR
> 00400 user has read permission
> S_IWUSR
> 00200 user has write permission
> S_IXUSR
> 00100 user has execute permission
> S_IRWXG
> 00070 group has read, write and execute permission
> S_IRGRP
> 00040 group has read permission
> S_IWGRP
> 00020 group has write permission
> S_IXGRP
> 00010 group has execute permission
> S_IRWXO
> 00007 others have read, write and execute permission
> S_IROTH
> 00004 others have read permission
> S_IWOTH
> 00002 others have write permission
> S_IXOTH
> 00001 others have execute permission

from https://linux.die.net/man/2/open

Comment: Not sure if OP is using Linux, but `O_RDWR` has the same value as `S_IWOTH` on Linux, so the `creat` call probably would have worked if that was the only thing wrong. (There might be another problem.)

Comment: This can not cause the failure.  [`creat(path,mode)` is identical to `open(path, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode);`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/creat.html)

Comment: @AndrewHenle It depends on the OS, because OP has set `mode` to `O_RDWR` which might not correspond to a valid mode.

Comment: @IanAbbott [The `mode` value should have no effect on the actual opening of the file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/open.html):  "... The argument following the `oflag` argument does not affect whether the file is open for reading, writing, or for both. ..."  In other words, if the file is opened for writing with `O_WRONLY`, setting the `mode` to `0444` won't stop the file from being opened for writing and then being written to.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That also says "When bits other than the file permission bits are set, the effect is unspecified." so it is a bit ambiguous!

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are probably correct though because no errors are listed for invalid mode. (And as an example implementation, the Linux kernel bit-wise ANDs the mode with mask of supported bits.)